# How to use Agora SDK for Recording multiple Audio channels simultaneously

Tags: python, live-streaming, agora.io, voice-recording

I used Python and [Agora-Python-SDK](https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/Agora-Python-SDK) package. But the API reference for Python is on proceeding. However it is very similar to "[Agora C++ API](https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/API%20Reference/cpp/v3.1.2/index.html)". you can use [this Documentation](https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/API%20Reference/cpp/v3.1.2/index.html) instead. Also, if you can just help in C++, it is still good. thanks for your help!

In addition, i needed to record channels silently and mute. without playback any sounds on device. And I think if that works on multi threads is better.

```
import agorartc
import threading

channel_name = 'MdgE1K2g' #for example

# Set some global variables
try:
    RTC = agorartc.RtcEngineBridge()
    eventHandler = agorartc.RtcEngineEventHandlerBase()
    RTC.initEventHandler(eventHandler)
    # 0xFFFFFFFE will exclude Chinese servers from Agora's servers.
    RTC.initialize(Clubhouse.AGORA_KEY, None, agorartc.AREA_CODE_GLOB & 0xFFFFFFFE)
    # Enhance voice quality
    if RTC.setAudioProfile(
            agorartc.AUDIO_PROFILE_MUSIC_HIGH_QUALITY_STEREO,
            agorartc.AUDIO_SCENARIO_GAME_STREAMING
        ) < 0:
        print("[-] Failed to set the high quality audio profile")

except ImportError:
    RTC = None


# Check for the voice level.
if RTC:
    token = channel_info['token']
    RTC.joinChannel(token, channel_name, "", int(user_id))
    RTC.startAudioRecording ("%s.mp3"%channel_name, 32)
else:
    print("[!] Agora SDK is not installed.")
    print("    You may not speak or listen to the conversation.")
```

Comment: Hey, can you elaborate on what you mean by "record channels silently and mute". I'm not really clear on what's your use case here.

Comment: @Samyak: Thank you very much for your attention. specifically i want to extract and save "local mp3 file" as output from multiple live streaming audio channels simultaneously. Without playback any sound on the device speakers.

Comment: I think your question has been answered here: https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/Agora-Python-SDK/issues/10. Let me know if this works.